# Splunk API search search/jobs/{search_id}/results

Tags: json, splunk

i have the problem to get the output in JSON format, it works with the default XML output. Command:

```
curl --silent -k -u {user}:{password} \
'https://{server}:8089/services/search/jobs/{search_id}/results/' 
\ -d output_mode=json
```

It works without `-d output_mode=json`, but I get the XML output.

Any ideas? Sorry for the dumbass question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `output_mode` in the query string, ie:

```
curl --silent -k -u {user}:{password} \
'https://{server}:8089/services/search/jobs/{search_id}/results/?output_mode=json'
```